# How can I build constructions on top of a Quetzal?

Tags: ark-survival-evolved

I would like to know how I can make contructions on a **[Quetzal](http://ark.gamepedia.com/Quetzal)** to employ it as a mass carrier.

The images below are just to describe what I mean.

[image: A Quetzal with stuff on its back]

[image: View from above]

Comment: What the hell that reviewer... instead of giving a downvote and modifying my question to be another total different thing, read the rules and the tag descriptions before editting any other question of any other OP. Thanks.

Comment: The edit was an attempt to keep the question on-topic.  As it stands, asking for mods that do specific things is off-topic.

Comment: He just removed all on-topic tags.

Comment: Check the edit again; it was an attempt at salvaging the question, and remove irrelevant tags.

Comment: This question is not about Steam or the Steam Workshop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can build constructions on a Quetzal that is wearing a [Quetz Platform Saddle](http://ark.gamepedia.com/Quetz_Platform_Saddle). This was added to the base game with [Patch 218](http://ark.gamepedia.com/218.0) in October 2015, and does not require additional mods.

Unlocking the Engram for construction requires the player to be level 80, and already have the [Quetz Saddle](http://ark.gamepedia.com/Quetz_Saddle) engram.

Alternatively they can be randomly found in [Deep Sea Loot Crates](http://ark.gamepedia.com/Deep_Sea_Loot_Crates), but this is unreliable, and these can only be opened by a player who is level 80 anyways.

Comment: Thankyou so much for your two answers, now I realize that my question was very stupid ... since it is not a mod.

Comment: @ElektroStudios This is why questions asking specifically for a mod to accomplish something are off-topic here. Maybe you'd be so kind to revert your edit now?

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer you mean if I'll do a rollback of a edit? in this question or in the other? it is necessary to do it? (I'm "scared" to spoil/lose something important whit the rollback option, I never did it)